# How to read EXE bytes, store into a char array, and then write the bytes into a new EXE file?

Tags: c++, byte

I am trying to read bytes from an EXE file, send the bytes via socket, and then write the bytes into another EXE file. The problem is that when I write the bytes to a EXE file and then try to open the EXE, Windows throws me an error:

[image]

Here is my code for reading the bytes from the original EXE file:

```
if (newConnection == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Error accepting connection\n\n" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << IP << " successfully connected to the client.\n\n" << std::endl;

    std::ifstream fl("C:\\readbyte.exe");
    fl.seekg(0, fl.end);
    int length = fl.tellg();
    char *buffer = new char[length];
    fl.seekg(0, fl.beg);
    fl.read((char*)buffer, length);
    fl.close();
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    send(newConnection, (char*)buffer, length, 0);

}
```

And here is my code for writing the bytes to a new EXE file:

```
if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) // if we are unable to connet
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to connect", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

}
else
{
    std::cout << "Connected to server.\n" << std::endl;

    std::vector<char> file(11776);
    std::cout << "Test1" << std::endl;
    if (recv(Connection, (char*)&file[0], file.size(), 0) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Test2" << std::endl;
        puts("Recv failed\n");
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Test3" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "File recieved: " << std::endl;

        /*for (int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << file[i];
            if (int(file[i]) == 0)
            {
                file.erase(file.begin() + i);
            }

        }*/
        const char *path = "C:/Users/Public/writefile.exe";
        std::ofstream fout(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        fout.flush();
        fout.write((char*)&file[0], file.size());
        fout.close();


        std::cout << "File size is: " << file.size() << std::endl;

        closesocket(Connection);
    }
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I've been working on this for 2 days now.

EDIT: ANSWER

```
std::ifstream fl("C:\\readbyte.exe", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

I forgot to include `std::ios::out | std::ios::binary` in the server `ifstream`. 
I also switched the out and binary arguments around.

Comment: That worked great! I think my problem was on the server file where I read the original file I didnt include ios::out and ios::binary. How do I mark your comment as the solution?

Comment: `std::ifstream` is an INPUT stream, whereas `std::ios::out` is for OUTPUT instead. DO NOT use `out` with `ifstream`. In this case, all you need is to add `std::ios::binary` to both streams. And FYI, when dealing with bit masks, the order of values used with `operator|` does not matter.

Comment: Yeah i feel so dumb I forgot to read the file in bytes, I thought that the way I was storing the buffer was wrong and receiving it. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode (give `std::ios::binary` as 2nd argument to `ifstream`)